# how to insert data with count in looping

Tags: c#

i have a sample data in table like this :

MasterData :

```
================================
data1 | data2 | totalDestination
================================
car     motor      des01;des02
```

and from my code, I want to insert data into another table like this:
Transaction :

```
==============================
data1 | data2 | idDestination
==============================
car     motor    des01
car     motor    des02
```

this is my code right now:

```
string TotalId = "des01;des02";
char[] delimiterChars = {';'};
string[] countx = TotalId.Split(delimiterChars);
foreach (string s in countx)
{
    " what i can do it in looping? "
}
```

my question : how to insert with count looping in my foreach ?
please give me solution.

Comment: If you actually need the index variable, you might be better off with a simple `for`-loop.

Comment: Just insert `data1=original_data1, data2=original_data2, totalDestination=s` into table

Comment: If you are using SQL i suggest you check to make this a trigger. then te second table would be populated automatically without the need of your application. And if you ever have another application inserting in the same table the logic would already be there

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

First, you can use a counter:

```
int index = 0;
foreach (string s in countx)
{
    // use index variable

    index++; // increment index
}
```

Better would be the use of a `for` loop:

```
for (int index = 0; index < countx.Length; index++)
{
    string s = countx[index]; // get the actual item

    // use index variable
}
```

Comment: Don't use a foreach loop - this is exactly what the for.

Comment: I agree. Just wanted to give options :)

Comment: (I'm playing devils advocate here) Options are good, but shouldn't we be `pushing` people down the correct way? (Opinion based!)

Comment: In mu opinion the 'best' solution is clearly marked 'better would be' (although not on top). It all depends on the use of the variable (in this case, `for` seems the only good solution.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, i get value [0] "des01". [1] "des02". so, how do I apply for the insert as many as 2 x according to the results in the table that I want. please, finish on my code snippet above :)

Comment: Are you asking how to insert the data in the database? What database platform? I don't see any database code in your question.

Comment: because the first step I want to do is separate the "totalDestination" into how much data the separation results. then entered into the table. please look at the picture on the table my questions. thanks...

Comment: But where is all the other code then?

Comment: With @PatrickHofman on this one - please explain FULLY what you want...

Answer (score -1):

Fist of all, I think that you would be better of with Objects instead of String for the totalDestination, but since you want it like that I won't argue about it.

I believe, (haven't tested it thought) is that you don't need an index on foreach. Since `s` is a string, you just get the string from the array and that's it.

```
foreach (string s in countx)
{
Sting idDestination =s;
}
```

I don't remember how C does this, but I am sure this should work